# What are the planets that appear in “Star Wars: Episode VII: The Force Awakens?”

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I was surprised when I realised that Jakku was not the camp Rey was scavenging/living at but the name of the entire planet show grew up on.  I had assumed early on in the movie she was on Tatooine as both other trilogies started there. Following that, I tried to keep track of the names of other planets shown and failed miserably. This is odd because I am familiar with most of the names of planets in the other trilogies.

What are the names of all of the planets shown in *Star Wars: Episode VII: The Force Awakens*?

Comment: This movie doesnt really mention the planet names like most of the other ones did

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Appearing as a planet in the film:** (I tried to order in the chronology of being seen on screen)

- [Jakku](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jakku)

  The planet where Rey lived and the one we see at the start of the film

  New to canon. It was first mentioned in pre-sequel novel "Aftermath".
- [Takodana](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Takodana)

  The "outlaw hangout" planet run by Maz Kanata and where the crew arrives

  New to canon.
- Unnamed planet where

  > Knights of Ren attacked in Rey's vision.
- [D'Qar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/D'Qar)

  The main base of the Resistance, where Leia is based

  New to canon. First appeared in *Lost Stars* book.
- Unnamed "white world" planet that First Order

  > turned into Starkiller weapon
- [Hosnian Prime](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hosnian_Prime) - the *current* seat of the Republic

  > destroyed

  New to canon.
- 4 other unnamed planets in Hosnian system

  > destroyed
- Unnamed ocean planet at the end of the film where

  > Luke Skywalker is hiding out

  As of right now, [the screenplay sent to WGA](http://www.slashfilm.com/star-wars-the-force-awakens-ending/) calls it "AHCH-TO", which was [confirmed by Pablo Hidalgo's "This is not canon twitter" account](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/682745067392471040)

**Mentioned in the film:**

- Trillia (presumed to be a planet where Trillia Massacre occured)
- Alderaan (in the context of its destruction - mentioned in novelization)

Comment: But that doesn't make sense, jakku was a desert planet. How is the very first planet jakku? It's a white planet, and by the looks of the scene, you're looking up at it as kylo Ren's ship passes over and the assault craft head down towards jakku.

Comment: Unless BB-8 jumped on some kind of transport, Jakku has to be the planet upon which was the base that was raided by the First Order.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_VII_The_Force_Awakens), the following planets are seen in The Force Awakens:

- Jakku
- Takadona
- Hosnian Prime
- D'Qar
- Starkiller Base

(Assuming you consider Starkiller Base a planet, which is sort of is.)

Comment: From the article you cite: "R2-D2 suddenly awakes and reveals that he holds the map to Luke's location, with the only piece of the map missing being the one BB-8 was given by Poe. Together they complete the map and reveal the location of Ahch-To, the planet on which Luke Skywalker sought out the first Jedi Temple."